# How to change base url endpoint for errai jaxrs proxy?

Tags: gwt, jax-rs, errai

I' need to call different endpoint located on different server, i  try to change value of base url of my rest services.

but i found only this method

```
 RestClient.create(MyService.class, otherServiceBaseUrl,
            myCallback,               
            200).doStaf() ;
```

Any suggestion to more elegant way for setup the base url for all services in my MyService class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution.
I create a abstract class DinamicCaller.

```
   public abstract class DinamicCaller<T> {


    public T call() {
        T call = getCaller().call();
        ((AbstractJaxrsProxy) call).setBaseUrl(getBaseUrl());
        return call;
    }

    public T call(RemoteCallback<?> callback) {
        T call = getCaller().call(callback);
        ((AbstractJaxrsProxy) call).setBaseUrl(getBaseUrl());

        return call;
    }

    public T call(RemoteCallback<?> callback, ErrorCallback<?> errorCallback) {

        T call = getCaller().call(callback, errorCallback);
        ((AbstractJaxrsProxy) call).setBaseUrl(getBaseUrl());

        return call;

    }

    protected abstract Caller<T> getCaller();


    protected abstract String getBaseUrl();
}
```

I create a Concrete Class

```
public class CallerCORSNegoziService extends DinamicCaller<CORSNegoziService> {

    @Inject
    NegozioManager negozioManager;
    @Inject
    Caller<CORSNegoziService> caller;


    @Override
    protected Caller<CORSNegoziService> getCaller() {
        return caller;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getBaseUrl() {
        return negozioManager.getNegozio().getUrl();
    }
}
```

On my class I inject the concrete class

```
@Inject
CallerCORSNegoziService service;
```

And I use it

```
@UiHandler("testButton")
public void testButtonClick(ClickEvent event) {
      service.call(testCallback, testCallback).findAllNegozi();
}
```

Is ugly but work.